# ¿Como Proteger una aplicacion winforms c# de ataques simples o errores de seguridad?

Tags: c#, sql

quería saber si saben de métodos simples para proteger aplicación básica en C# WinForms? me explico tengo una aplicación algo sencilla pero con un cierto nivel de seguridad, las contraseñas están encriptadas y todo, pero como he visto en algunos casos con sistemas web, existen formas de saltarse la seguridad con inyección SQL, ahora bien hay forma de protegerse de eso en WinForms o no seria muy necesario? básicamente busco evitar inyecciones del tipo: [‘OR ‘1’=’1]
he intentado buscar en Google pero no encuentro nada muy concreto y solo orientado a web.
De antemano gracias por el aporte.

Comment: esto esta basado en opiniones...

Comment: La respuesta es exactamente la misma para web o para escritorio...

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada siempre debes validar todas las entradas que haga el usuario, sobretodo en cadenas de caracteres eliminar o reemplazar algunos caracteres como la comilla simple ('), el punto y coma (;) o dos guiones seguidos (--) por poner unos ejemplos. También podrías usar procedimientos almacenados en lugar de escribir la consulta como tal.
En cuanto al momento de ejecutar SQL lo recomendado en la documentación es usar parámetros SQL para comprobar fácilmente el tipo de dato y la longitud que debería tener, por ejemplo:

```
SqlDataAdapter myCommand = new SqlDataAdapter("AuthorLogin", conn);
myCommand.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
SqlParameter parm = myCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@au_id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11);  
parm.Value = Login.Text;
```

Aqui encontraras algo mas de información: [Microsoft Docs - SQL Injection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: de esta forma lo hago yo: SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
                    SqlCmd.Connection = Con;
                    SqlCmd.CommandText = "Ingreso_Consultas_Blancas_Exitosas";
                    SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlParameter ParIdUsuario = new SqlParameter();
                    ParIdUsuario.ParameterName = "@Id_Usuario";
                    ParIdUsuario.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
                    ParIdUsuario.Value = cod;
                    SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(ParIdUsuario);

Comment: quedo feo ese comentario, sorry pero bueno es parecido a eso que comentas, solo se va separando el tipo de parametro, longitud etc

Comment: no respondas preguntas basadas en opiniones.